# Parse raw SMTP email data to get the HTML part (including links)

Tags: javascript, html, email, smtp, smtp-server

I am building a Javascript email client for testing purposes.

This client uses [smtp-server](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/) to recieve emails. This works fine.
However, the recieved content looks like this:

```html
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--_NmP-8304c67023835a47-Part_1"
From: "Radar Reflector >" <noreply@something.com>
To: D.Duck@home.ds
Subject: My Subject
Message-ID: <cc346fe1-f372-494a-4fd8-7aadf1872a98@somethis.com>
Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 15:16:14 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0

----_NmP-8304c67023835a47-Part_1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Some text here.
----_NmP-8304c67023835a47-Part_1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Dear you,<br />
Go to this link: <a href=3D"http://mysite.=
vagrant/api/v1/invites/route/invite/JDJhJDEwJGJyc3RQZk5KbEs2T2wveTQ2MmxP=
NWVITUdkVWhqS3ZpdzlKd3ZWU0RlVVFVOTRwbkdXYT/1">Invite Link</a><br />
<br />
Kind regards,<br />
<br />
- Somebody<br />
----_NmP-8304c67023835a47-Part_1--
```

As you can see, the link address starts with `3D` and the dot (`.`) has been replaced with dot-equal (`.=`).
When I use another mail client (mailcatcher), I can view the HTML content and it shows the correct address (`http://mysite.vagrant/api/v1/invites/route/aanmelden/JDJhJDEwJGJyc3RQZk5KbEs2T2wveTQ2MmxPNWVITUdkVWhqS3ZpdzlKd3ZWU0RlVVFVOTRwbkdXYT/1`).

What kind of encoding is used?
How can I translate the HTML-part so that is contains the correct link?

Comment: `What kind of encoding is used?` It says right there: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`

Comment: Thank you. I should have seen that.